# How to write recursion where items depend on each other?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, recursion, reduce

I want to write a function, which returns a list of people a person relies on.  However, the people relied upon, could in turn rely on the person themselves.  For example:

```
const people = {
    'james': {
        reliesOn: [
            'gemma',
            'jessica'
        ]
    },
    jessica: {
        reliesOn: [
            'gemma',
            'peter'
        ]
    },
    peter: {
        reliesOn: [
            'james',
            'gemma',
            'jessica',
            'ivon',
            'jamie'
        ]
    },
    jamie: {
        reliesOn: [
            'ivon'
        ]
    }
}
```

I am attempting to get the following result, *in the simplest possible code*:

james relies on:
    gemma, jessica, peter, ivon, jamie

jessica relies on:
    gemma, peter, james, ivon, jamie

peter relies on:
    james, gemma, jessica, ivon, jamie

jamie relies on:
    ivon

Apologies if this has already been asked.  I simplified this example from real world, so I hope it makes sense

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: apologies, I just saw this after the question was answered.  But my code was a mess, so I didn't post it initially

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to do this with `reduce` then:

```js
const getReliedOn = (people, name) =>
    [...(people[name]?.reliesOn || []).reduce(function recur(acc, name) {
        return acc.has(name) ? acc 
            :  (people[name]?.reliesOn || []).reduce(recur, acc.add(name));
    }, new Set([name]))].slice(1);

// Sample input
const people = {'james': { reliesOn: ['gemma','jessica']}, jessica: {reliesOn: ['gemma','peter']}, peter: {reliesOn: ['james','gemma','jessica','ivon','jamie']}, jamie: { reliesOn: ['ivon']}};
// Produce output for each person:
for (let name in people) console.log(name, "=>", ...getReliedOn(people, name));
```

#### Alternative without `reduce`, without recursion

This is a breadth-first search (BFS). It relies on the fact that when you iterate over a set, and during that iteration you add values to that set, the loop will also visit those added values in later iterations. So the set acts like the queue that is typical for a BFS:

```js
function getReliedOn(people, name) {
    let names = new Set([name]); // a set with only one entry
    for (let name of names) { // this set will extend while we loop
         if (!people[name]) continue;
         for (let other of people[name].reliesOn) names.add(other);
    }
    // get normal array from set, without original name
    return Array.from(names).slice(1);
}

// Sample input
const people = {'james': { reliesOn: ['gemma','jessica']}, jessica: {reliesOn: ['gemma','peter']}, peter: {reliesOn: ['james','gemma','jessica','ivon','jamie']}, jamie: { reliesOn: ['ivon']}};
// Produce output for each person:
for (let name in people) console.log(name, "=>", ...getReliedOn(people, name));
```

Comment: Hi @trincot, thank you for your reply.  If I did not not need to use `reduce`, what would be the simplest code to achieve this? Apologies, I found it hard to understand this code

Comment: apologies if the `reduce` bit of the question was too constraining, I have removed it from the question.  Ideally I wanted the simplest possible code to resolve the problem

Comment: I added an alternative solution, with a bit of comments. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: Thank you so much, the alternative solution is very elegant and it works! I really appreciate your help @trincot!

Answer (score 1):

I find it useful to pass around a "memo" object when recursing that keeps track of where we've been already to avoid circular loops:

```
function *getDependenciesRecursive(people, person, alreadyVisited = new Set()) {
  if (alreadyVisited.has(person)) {
    return;
  }
  alreadyVisited.add(person);

  if (!(person in people)) {
    return;
  }

  for (const dependency of people[person].reliesOn) {
    yield dependency;
    yield* getDependenciesRecursive(people, dependency, alreadyVisited);
  }
}
```

Essentially, in an approach like this the `Set` tells us what to skip.

```
const reliances = Object
  .entries(people)
  .reduce((results, [person, { reliesOn }]) => Object.assign(results, {
    [person]: [...getDependenciesRecursive(people, person)]
  }), {})
```

Comment: Hi @jacob, thank your the help, but when I run this I get undefined: `console.log(getDependenciesRecursive(people, 'james'));`.  I have modified the code to not use generators